# NSString to NSNumber for large numbers

Tags: nsstring, nsnumber, nsnumberformatter

I have a NSString which contains a very large number. I need to convert this to a NSNumber, but it's always returning a NSNumber in scientific format, which isn't good (I'm using the number in a predicate, to search for a music track with this MPMediaEntityPropertyPersistentID).

```
NSNumberFormatter *numberFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[numberFormatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];

NSString *str = @"14881035034468747982";
DLog(@"before: %@", str);
NSNumber *nmb = [numberFormatter numberFromString:str];
DLog(@"after: %@", nmb);
```

Prints:

```
<AppDelegate.m:199> before: 14881035034468747982
<AppDelegate.m:201> after: 1.488103503446875e+19
```

If I use this number to search the iPod library, nothing is returned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid I was a bit too quick with asking this question. Once I figured out that the number in question is an unsigned long long, finding the answer wasn't that hard.

```
unsigned long long ullvalue = strtoull([str UTF8String], NULL, 0);
NSNumber *nmb = @(ullvalue);
```

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar problem when pulling out a **MPMediaEntityPropertyPersistentID** that I had stored in a local **sqLite3** DB.  Thought another code fragment may help someone:

```
// convert the uniqueId for the track into an NSNumber 

NSString *longString = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 11)];
unsigned long long ullvalue = strtoull([longString UTF8String], NULL, 0);
NSNumber *UniqueId = [NSNumber numberWithUnsignedLongLong:ullvalue];
```